# Can I devote more room to my voicemails?

Tags: iphone, voicemail, visual-voicemail

I have an iPhone 4S with plenty of space on it but I keep lots of voicemails...to the point where sometimes people can't leave me a message because my voicemail is full.  Is this an iPhone thing that I can adjust or is it strictly a Verizon thing?  Most of the voicemails I keep are of my kids...and I know I can save those off as audio files...but I'd rather just use the space on my phone.

Thanks!
Drew

Answer (score 3):

Voicemail is handled by the carrier. The size of your mailbox depends on the plan & features you have with Verizon, not on the free space available on your phone.

I doubt Verizon will keep old messages indefinitely, so if there are messages that are important to you, you should save backup audio files of them. Then clear out old messages to make space to receive new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Verizon Wireless WILL hold all iPhone voicemail messages indefinitely IF you do not switch from an iPhone. If you switch to an Android or other device, your messages will be lost permanently. The voicemail messages do not reside on the iPhone but reside on Verizon servers.