# What determines the limit on voicemail storage on an iPhone 7?

Tags: iphone, storage, voicemail

My iPhone 7 stopped taking voicemails. I dialed it from a different number and got the automated message, "voice mailbox is full." I contacted my carrier, Credo Mobile, and they explained that voicemail storage occurs on the iPhone, not in my carrier account.

On the iPhone 7, I went into Settings, General, iPhone Storage, Phone, and saw that Voicemails took up **only 12.3MB**. (This was after I had deleted some voicemails and was again able to leave a message.)

Is there, then, some constant, fixed, number of bytes that my phone can store as voicemail? Or is it a fixed number of messages? Or if I reduce the amount stored by some other app---say, Voice Memos, which today uses a **whopping 14.86GB**---will there be more room for voicemails?

These are not several questions, it is a single question with several possible suggested answers.

(Because of spam phone calls and robocalls, there is a steady drizzle of unwanted voicemails into my iPhone 7 so that even if no one calls me that I care about, the voice mailbox will get full.)

Note that one response to [Can I devote more room to my voicemails?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51187/can-i-devote-more-room-to-my-voicemails) states, in the context of Verizon,

> Voicemail is handled by the carrier. The size of your mailbox depends on the plan & features you have with Verizon, not on the free space available on your phone.

But Credo Mobile customer service---a live human being speaking with me---unequivocally stated the opposite for their service. In addition, when I logged into my account on Credo Mobile, https://www.credomobile.com/customer/account/login,
I found no option to set or change the amount of voicemail storage. Also, there are no voicemails in my online account. For instance, I cannot go online and listen to voicemails. There is no list of voicemails online.

Comment: I think your support human was incorrect.

Comment: @ⱮarkƬ what is the documentation or evidence for this? Do you have Credo Mobile?

Comment: If you turn your phone off, are you able to leave voicemail for yourself? For what it's worth, I know my voicemails are stored AT&T and Verizon side, and I also do not have the option to listen to voicemails online, or change the size of my voicemail box. I think it is more likely that the Credo mobile support person is simply confused, because your iPhone *can* store copies of voicemails - but that does not make it the mechanism by which voicemail is received.

Comment: Credo is an MVNO that re-sells Verizon.  Verizon stores voicemail on the network.  The phone doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Call your own phone, press # while the announcement is playing, enter your voicemail password.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever you spoke to one the phone was wrong, your carrier limits the *number* of voice mails you can have stored.

Comment: Voice mail storage is at the carrier.  This is why you can retrive them without the phone.